# can I remove/change the PORT in localhost when deploying?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

is there any chance that I can remove the `:3000` in my localhost? I'm trying to deploy my website locally and can only be accusable to other devices who are connected to my mobile hotspot.

```
  http://192.168.25.113:3000
```

So instead of search the whole Address, is there anyway I can shorten it like search just this

```
192.168.25.113
```

Or change the whole ip address name without buying domain and doing it locally? like renaming it to

`marketplace.shop`

I'm using **Nodejs** and **Express**

Answer (score -1):

The only way to avoid including the port number in the URL is to run the service on the default port for the protocol scheme you are using (in the case of HTTP that is port 80).

The only way to avoid including the protocol scheme is to enter it somewhere where it will be added automatically (e.g. typing it into the address bar of a browser). In other contexts it will usually be treated as a relative path URL (which is not going to be helpful).

The only way to get a domain name is to actually get a domain name. You can't just get the DNS to give you a name without registering it. (If you have control over the DNS server that your users use then you could make it ignore the global DNS for that particular name, but that's rarely practical outside of company Intranets).